# table has inside div press delete table my div element deleted in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I am using TinyMCE

I create my editor div element (selector) inside table element. Then I click delete table the div element is deleted.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>  <div class="tinymce-body">
<p>Here are some of our customer&rsquo;s most common use cases for TinyMCE:</p>
<ul>
<li>Content Management systems (<em>e.g. WordPress, Umbraco</em>)</li>
<li>Learning Management Systems (<em>e.g. Blackboard</em>)</li>
<li>Customer Relationship Management and marketing automation (<em>e.g. Marketo</em>)</li>
<li>Email marketing (<em>e.g. Constant Contact</em>)</li>
<li>Content creation in SaaS systems (<em>e.g. Eventbrite, Evernote, GoFundMe, Zendesk</em>)</li>
</ul>
<p>And those use cases are just the start. TinyMCE is incredibly flexible, and with hundreds of APIs there&rsquo;s likely a solution for your editor project. If you haven&rsquo;t experienced Tiny Cloud, get started today. You&rsquo;ll even get a free trial of our premium plugins &ndash; no credit card required!</p>  </div>      </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
selector: ".tinymce-body",
inline: true,
plugins: 'table',
toolbar: 'table'});
</script>
```

Code: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/zhfaab/3

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M68kq.png)

How to stop to this. Only allowed to delete '**inside the div element**' created tables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anyone reading this, [it's a bug](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/6173)